# Деплой React + Express (Клиент + Сервер) на хостинг/облако

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, хостинг

У меня приложение, две папки client (React) и server (Express), локально запускаю всё через терминал (сервер npm run dev, клиент npm client), всё работает как задумывалось. Попробовал залить всё это дело на облачный сервер, через ssh подключился и также в двух терминалах запустил, всё работает. Возник вопрос, как мне всё это дело задеплоить так, чтобы мне не приходилось постоянно в терминале в ручную запускать клиент + сервер через npm.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использоваьть pm2, подходит для многих задач.

Для установки на Windows: `npm install -g pm2`,
на Unix-подобных системах: `sudo npm install -g pm2`.

С помощью команды `pm2 init simple` или вручную создается конфигурационный файл `ecosystem.config.js`, где задаются [настройки](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) и указываются пути к серверу и клиенту:

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: "server",
            script: "./server/index.js", // путь к файлу с серверным кодом
            watch: true, // автоматический перезапуск при изменениях файлов
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: "production",
            },
        },
        {
            name: "client",
            script: "npm",
            args: "run client", // команда для запуска клиентской части (npm run client)
            cwd: "./client", // путь к папке с клиентским кодом
            watch: true, // автоматический перезапуск при изменениях файлов
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: "production",
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

Далее, в `package.json`, назначается команда для запуска приложения с помощью pm2: `"start": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js"`. После этого, вводя `npm start`, pm2 будет запускать приложение с заданными параметрами.

Документация по [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/905755)

Comment: @Amgarak  Абсолютно согласен с вами! Спасибо за ценную ремарку! Дополнил ответ по вопросу!